# Bar chart with customised width in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have this dataframe `df` which contains -

```
Name       Team Name        Category       Challenge      Points            Time
 A            B               1              1ABC           50       2019-11-04 07:37:02        
 D            B               2              2ACE          150       2019-11-04 09:57:02
 X            P               4              4PQR          500       2019-11-05 08:45:02
 A            B               3              3PQR           10       2019-11-04 10:25:20
 N            P               4              4ABC          120       2019-11-05 08:35:00
 C            G               1              1ABC           50       2019-11-04 07:37:02
 D            B               4              4RST          200       2019-11-04 10:57:02
```

I have this ambitious plan of visualizing this dataset as a customised barchart where each team has a building (bar) made of different blocks of varying width (depending on the points asssociated with that challenge), and vertical order of blocks would be depending on the time (first one goes at the bottom). In short the plot for the above data should roughly look like this -

[image]

The different colours represent the different categories here. I know how to group the data by teams and then plot each teams number of attempts by -

```
df.groupby(['Team Name'])['Challenge'].count().plot.bar()
```

but beyond that, I'm clueless as to how to change the bar widths. Can someone help with this?
Alternatively, if someone has a better idea of how to visualise it using any of the conventional plots, I'd love to hear your opinions too.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected output at all? Total points of each team?

Comment: The length of the bar (Y-Axis) is the total number of challenges (count) attempted by each team. The points are to be visualised as the width of each block on the building.

Comment: I think you are looking for stacked bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this look like what you want?

[image]

You can accomplish this by manually plotting the 'blocks' via `matplotlib.patches`, it just requires some extra manipulation to do so algorithmically. Here is a complete example using the data supplied in the question

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

t20 = [(31, 119, 180), (174, 199, 232), (255, 127, 14), (255, 187, 120)]
for i in range(len(t20)):    
    r, g, b = t20[i]    
    t20[i] = (r / 255., g / 255., b / 255.)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df = df.sort_values('Time')
cat = df['Category'].unique()
cidx = dict(zip(cat, range(len(cat))))

mw = max(df['Points'])
names = list(df['Team Name'].unique())
nt = len(names)
h = 0.5
hs = [0]*3
for ii in range(len(df.index)):
    w = float(df['Points'].iloc[ii])/mw
    idx = names.index(df['Team Name'].iloc[ii])
    r = Rectangle((idx - w/2.0, hs[idx]), w, h, color=t20[cidx[df['Category'].iloc[ii]]])
    hs[idx] += 0.5
    ax.add_patch(r)
plt.xlim([-0.5, len(names)-0.5])
plt.ylim([0, max(hs)+3])
plt.xticks(range(len(names)), names)
plt.show()
```

I used the first 4 colors in the [tableau 20 palette](https://public.tableau.com/profile/chris.gerrard#!/vizhome/TableauColors/ColorPaletteswithRGBValues) in case you were interested.

---

#### Edit

You can add a legend with the line

```py
plt.legend(handles=[Patch(facecolor=t20[ii], label=cat[ii]) for ii in range(len(t20))])
```

as long as the additional import of `Patches` from `matplotlib.patches` is included, i.e.

```py
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle, Patch
```

And the output will be

[image: Plot with legend]

Comment: Yeesss!! :) Thank you!

Comment: how can I add a legend to this map based on the colours (categories)?

Comment: thanks a lot!! That's a lot easier than what I was trying.. :)

Comment: can you tell me how to add some outline to the individual bars and how to order this (for eg. I want them in order highest to lowest stacks B -> P -> G)?